# What does this norm expression mean?

Tags: real-analysis

$\|(x,y)\|_1^3 \le 5x + 7$,

I am kinda confused about the norm expression $\|(x,y)\|_1^3$ here, what does $^3$ and $_1$ mean by here separately?

Does $\|(x,y)\|_1^3$ mean $\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$ by here?

Comment: $||\cdot||_1$ usually denotes the norm given by $||(x,y)||_1=|x|+|y|$. However, from what you have written above, it is not possible to deduce the context, or the true definition. It is somewhat confusing since $x$ could be negative, which means the inequality is not possible if $x<-7/5$ for example.

Comment: @SamM Thank you! I use this inequality to define a convex set here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the $1$-norm raised to the $3$rd power: $$\left\| (x,y)\right\|^3_1 = \left(\left| x\right| + \left| y\right|\right)^3$$ Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) at $p$-norms.

Comment: It almost surely does.

Comment: @xxx222 You're welcome!